# How can I add more than one element to a JList?

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist

Apparently, the .setListData() method only allows an user to add one element at a time to a JList. I want to give the user the ability to add more than one element to the JList at one time.

Also .setListData() only adds more elements to the JList. Is there a way to have the newly added elements replace the existing elements in a JList?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation for setListData()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData(E[]))? It takes an array which allows multiple elements.

Comment: Edit your question and show your code.  I have the feeling you’re trying to pass a primitive array and/or you’re ignoring compiler warnings related to generics.  “the .setListData() method only allows an user to add one element at a time to a JList.” No, it doesn’t.  “.setListData() only adds more elements to the JList” No, it doesn’t.  I have successfully placed multiple items in a JList by calling setListData.  Many others have as well.  Probably thousands of others.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for JList:

> public void setListData(E[] listData)
>
> Constructs a read-only ListModel from an array of items, and calls setModel with this model.

Note the words "array of items". This means you can add more than one element at a time.